# Ask a step in Proof of L'Hospitals Rule

Tags: analysis

Suppose that $f$ and $g$ are differentiable functions on an open interval $I$ and that $p \in I$. If $\lim_{x \to p} f(x) = \lim_{x \to p} g(x) = 0$ and if

$$\lim_{x \to p} \frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}$$

exists and equals a real number $l$ then

$$\lim_{x \to p} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=l$$

Proof: Fix a real number $a > l$. By the definition of limit there is a number $q > p$ such that, if $p < x< q$, then $ \frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}<a$. I don't know how to derive this.

Comment: Do you mean $\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}<a$ instead of $\lim_{x \to p} \frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}=a$ at the end there?

Comment: Correct. Thank you pointing out my typo. I have changed there. And yes, I don't know how to get this.f'(x)/g'(x)<a

Comment: I think the bizarre "by the formula" must be a typo for "by the definition of limit".

Comment: You also didn't include the other indeterminate forms, like $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$.

Comment: I tried to think the definition of the limit of derivatives, but I didn't figure it out.

Comment: Thanks. Now I understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have $\lim_{x\to p}\big( \text{something}\big) = \ell.$

And you have $a>\ell.$

That implies that there is some open interval about $p$ for which, if $x$ is in that open interval and $x\ne p,$ then $\big(\text{something}\big) <a. $

Similarly if $b<\ell$ then there is some open interval about $p$ for which, if $x$ is in that open interval and $x\ne p,$ then $\big(\text{something})>b.$

This is a consequence of the definition of *limit*: No matter how small $\varepsilon>0$ is, there is some open interval about $p$ such that if $x$ is in that open interval and $x\ne p,$ then $\big(\text{something}\big)$ differs from $\ell$ by less than $\varepsilon.$ Generally as $\varepsilon$ gets smaller, that open interval about $p$ must get smaller.